# Get Record ID in Entity Framework 5 after insert

Tags: entity-framework, repository

I realize this must be a relatively simple thing to do, but I'm not getting what I'm looking for with Google.

I need to get the record ID of the record I just saved using the Entity Framework. With SQL queries we used "Select @@IDENTITY as 'Identity';"

If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default behavior of Entity Framework is it sets identity fields on entities from the database right after `SaveChanges` is called.

In the following sample code, before `SaveChanges` is called, my employee has a default ID of 0. After `SaveChanges` my employee has a generated ID of 1.

```
using (TestDbEntities context = new TestDbEntities())
{
    Employee e = new Employee ();
    e.FirstName = "John";
    e.LastName = "Doe";
    context.Employee.Add(e);
    context.SaveChanges();
    Console.WriteLine("Generated ID: {0}", e.ID);
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```